# How to reverse a word and comparing algorithms

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between the two types of code below?
Is there any problem in my own code or not? My code works well, but it's different from the guided solution code, so I'm curious.

My code:

```
def reverse(word)
  i = 1
  l = word.length

  letter = word[l-i]
  while i <= l-1

    letter += word[l-i-1]
    i += 1

  end

  return letter

end

puts reverse("cat")          # => "tac"
puts reverse("programming")  # => "gnimmargorp"
puts reverse("bootcamp")     # => "pmactoob"
```

The guided solution code:

```
def reverse(word)
  reversed = ""

  i = 0
  while i < word.length
    char = word[i]
    reversed = char + reversed

    i += 1
  end

  return reversed
end

puts reverse("cat")          # => "tac"
puts reverse("programming")  # => "gnimmargorp"
puts reverse("bootcamp")     # => "pmactoob"
```

Comment: If you want to learn both are ok, if you want to know how I would do in production "acb".reverse it's better .But if it's your code and you make it... we don't need to explain to you how you made it :)

Comment: @fikainsg : I find your solution a little bit odd, because you start to count the characters from 1; i.e. `i == 1` deals with the first character.  This requires you to write more complicated index expressions such as `word[l-i-1]`, which are often a source of an error. The proposed solution takes `i == 0` to denote the position of the first character, which is more natural and leads to simpler code.

Comment: In general, in most programming languages the second style of solution is better, because you are not modifying your inputs. This is safer, and easier to debug as you can see both your input and you're output. It also makes the coding simpler to write and easier to understand.

Comment: @user1934428 Your comment helps me a lot! Thank you : )

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I totally agree with you. I believe that I will be getting better : )

Comment: if comments, or answers are helpful, it is good practice to upvote them, if you have the rights.

Answer (score 0):

It's always interesting to compare the speed of various ways to do something. I added some additional methods to show how they'd compare:

```
require 'fruity'

def reverse1(word)
  i = 1
  l = word.length

  letter = word[l-i]
  while i <= l-1

    letter += word[l-i-1]
    i += 1

  end

  return letter

end

def reverse2(word)
  reversed = ""

  i = 0
  while i < word.length
    char = word[i]
    reversed = char + reversed

    i += 1
  end

  return reversed
end
# ---------------------------------
# my added methods
def reverse3(word)
  reversed = ''
  word.length.times do |i|
    reversed << word[-1 - i]
  end
  reversed
end

# a short, but naive, attempt
def reverse4(word)
  word.split('').reverse.join
end

# how we should do it
def reverse5(word)
  word.reverse
end

DA_STRING = 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis'

# confirm the methods return the same value
reverse1(DA_STRING) # => "sisoinoconaclovociliscipocsorcimartluonomuenp"
reverse2(DA_STRING) # => "sisoinoconaclovociliscipocsorcimartluonomuenp"
reverse3(DA_STRING) # => "sisoinoconaclovociliscipocsorcimartluonomuenp"
reverse4(DA_STRING) # => "sisoinoconaclovociliscipocsorcimartluonomuenp"
reverse5(DA_STRING) # => "sisoinoconaclovociliscipocsorcimartluonomuenp"

# time them
compare do
  reverse_1 { reverse1(DA_STRING) }
  reverse_2 { reverse2(DA_STRING) }
  reverse_3 { reverse3(DA_STRING) }
  reverse_4 { reverse4(DA_STRING) }
  reverse_5 { reverse5(DA_STRING) }
end
```

Running the code results in:

```
# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 7 seconds.
# >> reverse_5 is faster than reverse_3 by 36x ± 1.0
# >> reverse_3 is faster than reverse_1 by 50.0% ± 10.0%
# >> reverse_1 is similar to reverse_2
# >> reverse_2 is faster than reverse_4 by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
```

Answer (score -1):

Seem your guide considered mainly the following things.

- **Minimizing memory allocations** by reducing variable creations as much as possible.

  > Directly used `word.length` instead of creating a variable since the variable `l` will not be reuseable anywhere else in your case.
- **Minimizing process time** by reducing the no of operations as much as possible.

  > Seems the extra operations `word[l-i]`, `l-1` and `word[l-i-1]` are avoided in the guided program.

Comment: Minimizing processing time, it is better to assign the length to a variable, so it is only calculated once and the length isn't going to change. Depending on your compiler or interpreter, may be optimised into a register. Even if it's not, it will be allocated on the local stack, which is designed to be transient, so, in this case probably wouldn't alter the application's heap allocations.